# Finite State Machine for Generating Names One Letter at a Time

Tags: string, algorithm, random, state-machine, procedural-generation

I recall taking a class several years ago where I was given an interesting example of a finite state machine in which each state contained a letter and had multiple paths that led to other letters that generally followed them in a word. Some of the letters also had paths that led to a termination as well, and by starting at any point in the finite state machine and following valid paths to a termination, you could chain the letters together and (almost) always end up with a valid word. Of course this was only a subset of the words in the language (which unfortunately I forgot what language the FSM was meant for). My question involves multiple related questions:

- Is this a viable way to randomly generate a "pseudo" word? By that I mean a word that isn't necessarily valid, but one that's spelled in a way that looks valid.
- Is this technique used in, or as part of, any well-known random word generation algorithms, and if so, which ones?
- Are there other common alternatives to this that generate a random word one letter at a time, or possibly to take a random string that was generated in this manner and coerce it into a "pseudo" word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The rules

The correct answer for your case depends on the meaning of "pseudo-word", and how you want multiple generated pseudo-words to relate to each other. Since you've tagged this question with "procedural generation", I'll assume you want to construct a fake natural language; so:

1. Every word should be pronounceable. For example, 'gotrobit' would be acceptable, but 'grrhjklmpp' would not.
2. The general 'feel' of different words should be comparable; you don't want a set of finnish-sounding words intermixed with french-sounding words.

## General issues with FSMs

You can most certainly use a finite state machine to do this, but there are two possible pitfalls:

- If the FSM contains cycles, you can have wildly varying word lengths; this can be very bad for requirement #2. If your FSM does not contain cycles, you will end up with a huge FSM in order to generate a reasonable lexicon.
- You will need to be very careful when constructing your FSM, or you will end up with words that do not satisfy #1.

You could add a post-processing step where you filter out 'stupid' results, but as I will show later on, there are better options.

## Markov Chains

With these pitfalls in mind, a common way of seeding your FSM would be to use [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

For example, you can generate a non-determinate FSM where each state represents a character (or termination); you then analyze a corpus of e.g. English texts to calculate the possibility that a specific character is followed by another character, and use that to create your transitions.

Using Markov chains makes it easier to reach goal #2; by using e.g. a corpus of German texts, you get a completely different set of words that still somewhat resemble each other.

As said, the pitfalls remain. For example, look at the words "art" and "train". This implies that a 't' can follow an 'r', but also that an 'r' can follow a 't'. Based on these examples, you can end up with words like "trtrtrain", which in my eye violates #1.

This can be somewhat alleviated by having each state represent a combination of 2 characters, instead of one, but this will quickly lead to a state explosion.

## Syllables

A much more promising approach is to not generate your words letter by letter, but syllable by syllable. You start by generating a list of allowed syllables, determine your preferred word length in syllables, and pick that amount of syllables.

For example, you can start by using a list of all consonant+vowel syllables. This will give you words like "tokuga" and "potarovo". You can also use a list of vowel+consonant syllables, which would give you words like "otukag" and "opatorov": a completely different 'language' with the same simple rules.

Of course, this gets tricky when you would e.g. allow both consonant+vowel and single-vowel syllables. Now you can end up with words like "tokuuauga", which may or may not be what you want.

You can go a bit further, classify the types of syllables and add some simple rules such as: "only two single-vowel syllables can follow each other"; or "every consonant-vowel syllable followed by a single-vowel syllable must be followed by a consonant-vowel-consonant syllable". Now you can end up with words like "tokuugat".

By choosing the set of allowed syllables and rules, you can get different 'languages' that feel somewhat coherent.

## Using phonemes

If you want to make even better words, you should start by using [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) instead of letters. This allows you to easily represent non-ASCII sounds such as "ng", "sh" and (tongue-click). You then follow the algorithm as described above, followed by a "transliteration" step where you change the phonemes into 'readable' letters.

By using different transliterations, you can get even more 'language'-like feelings. For example, you can transliterate /sh/ like 'sh' (english), or 'ch' (french) or 'sch' (dutch).

## Phonological rules

[Phonological rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_rule) are basically a formal way of describing the rules from the previous section, going a bit further than my previous example. By choosing the correct set of rules, you can create 'hard' languages, 'soft' languages, etc. For example, you can choose to have 'vowel+r+k+vowel' to be changed to 'vowel+r+r+vowel' (resulting in a language that sounds like a motor) or to be changed to 'vowel+k+h+vowel' (resulting in a typical dwarfish language). The possibilities are endless.

Phonological research has produced a lot of these rules, helping you to create more earth-like languages.

A nice example of this approach is [Drift](http://valdyas.org/python/drift.html), a Python program that uses a list of syllables and a set of phonological rules to generate 'real' words.

Leaving the randomness and computer-generated aspects aside, I believe this is more or less the approach Tolkien used when he generated his elvish languages and dialects.

## Conclusion

To sum up the answers:

- Yes, using an FSM is a viable approach
- Markov chains are a popular technique to create such FSMs
- You get better results by using syllables and the research done in phonology

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: Dude, that answer was wonderful. It doesn't only contain real good answer, but also is actual fun to read. Bravo.

Comment: This is amazing and EXACTLY what I have been looking for, great answer overall. Before I found this I was just whitelisting consonants and vowels, but now I can apply it.